# DrawImage doubt

Tags: javascript, html5, image

What is the best option for animation in a game (HTML5 Javascript)? Put all the images in one png and change the background.

Or create each image separately and draw with `DrawImage`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Texture Atlas, or as I call it, a Sprite Map.  This is especially important for Javascript as it reduces the number of HTTP requests to the server. For example, 8 frames = 8 HTTP requests for non-mapped images.

Another advantage of using a Sprite Map is the fact that canvas already supports drawing 'sliced' images.  When drawing an image, you can define a sourceX & sourceY as well as a targetX & targetY.  In my engine this is exactly how I handled animations.

```
ctx.drawImage( data, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

"To measure is to know" as the saying goes. Try both methods and see what works.

**Drawing each image separately**

Advantages:

- Lots of detail in your images.
- Fast artistic pipeline. Adding a new image doens't take much time, because it's just an image in a folder.
- Grouping can reduce image swapping. If your trees all use `tree1.png`, make a `TreeGroup` that attaches that image and renders all your trees.

Disadvantages:

- Easy to go over budget. Your images might be too large for your game and fixing it might take too much time.
- Image swapping. Constantly swapping out images can reduce framerate significantly.

**Texture atlas**

A [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) is a large texture that contains all smaller textures used in (a section of) the game.

Advantages:

- No swapping of images. All your sprites use the same image, just with different coordinates. This can be a speed benefit.

Disadvantages:

- Less detailed images. Everything has to fit in one image, so each image won't get as much space.
- Less artistic flexibility. It's hard for artists to fit all those images on a single large image.

Most likely you'll end up with a combination of the two techniques: a texture atlas for small, static objects and high-resolution images for your dynamic objects.